# Convert Python to exe

Tags: python, converters

I wrote a program in PyCharm and wanted to convert it into an exe. I tried to use multiple programs like `auto-py-to-exe` or `pyinstaller`, but no one has imported my self wirtten modules. Does someone know how I can so this?

Comment: After converting using pyinstaller, it will create a spec file. Try editing the spec file created and in the datas list, add all your self written modules

Comment: You need to tell them to include your self written modules